# I can't fix a error talking about members in swiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm new to swift UI and i need help with an error i received. The question is "Value of type 'MotionView' has no member 'tiltOutput'". I do not know were to add a member in my code.

Ive have tried making new vars.

```
var tiltOut = 0

struct MotionView: View {
  @State private var labelText: String = "tiltOutput"
  var motionManager = CMMotionManager()
  var body: some View {
    Text(self.labelText)
      .onAppear {
        self.startGyro()
      }
  }

  func startGyro() {
    motionManager.gyroUpdateInterval = 0.2
    motionManager.startGyroUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!) {        
     (data, Error) in

     if let myData = data
     {
       if myData.rotationRate.y > 3
       {
          tiltOut = tiltOut + 1
          self.tiltOutput.text = "\(tiltOut)"
       }
```

The error is:

```
"Value of type 'MotionView' has no member 'tiltOutput'"
```

and i get it at line:

```
self.tiltOutput.text = "\(tiltOut)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error clearly states there is no member tiltOutput, the correct way is to alter labelText, as follow:

Instead of:

```
self.tiltOutput.text = "\(tiltOut)"
```

Do:

```
self.labelText = "\(tiltOut)"
```